# How to use unscoped enumerator as if its type is its underlying type

Tags: c++

This doesn't work as expected:

```
template<typename T>
struct PHI {
    enum : T { value = 11400714819323198485 >> (64 - sizeof(T) * 8) };
};

std::cout << PHI<unsigned long long>::value;
```

The output is `2135587861`. What I expected is `11400714819323198485`.(In VS2013)

I thought `PHI<unsigned long long>::value` would implicitly convert to type `unsigned long long` if needed. But it actually convert to `unsigned`. That means when I used it in some other place, it might convert to `unsigned` too. That's not what I want.

Comment: works in g++/clang++. What is the `sizeof` of `unsigned long long` in VS? (probably 8 but doesn't hurt to check)

Comment: Why not `static const T value = ...`?

Comment: Interesting. If you do `static_cast<unsigned long long>(PHI<unsigned long long>::value)` then the value is preserved. And similarly if you only have an `unsigned long long` overload, the value is preserved too. So the problem is somewhere in the overload resolution that picked the `unsigned int` overload rather than the `unsigned long long` one...

Comment: VS's debugger doesn't like it either. Storing it like so `auto x = PHI<unsigned long long>::value;` just shows `value` in QuickWatch. You can't even step into the `std::cout`. Looks like it can't detect it's type.

Comment: @Axalo Of course, `value` is still of an unnamed, unscoped enumeration type.

Comment: Try: `value = 11400714819323198485ULL`.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, you are right I just realized that too, I was going to edit the comment anyway. But still, it's strange that you can't step into cout.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for my pool English. Feel free to correct it.

Comment: Workaround: `std::cout << +PHI<unsigned long long>::value;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get rid of the templates. Minimized repro:

```
#include <iostream>

enum bar : unsigned long long { baz = 11400714819323198485ULL };

void foo(int v) { std::cout << "int "<< v; }
void foo(unsigned v) { std::cout << "uint " << v; }
void foo(unsigned long long v) { std::cout << "ull " << v; }

int main() { foo(baz); }
```

This prints `uint 2135587861`.

Meanwhile,

```
#include <iostream>

enum bar : unsigned long long { baz = 11400714819323198485ULL };

void foo(unsigned long long v) { std::cout << "ull " << v; }

int main() { foo(baz); }
```

prints `ull 11400714819323198485`. So the value is preserved, and the conversion can be done. This looks like a bug in VC++'s overload resolution. This also reproduces in VS2015 CTP5.

**Edit**: reported as https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1131433

The shortest workaround appears to be using `foo(+baz)`; the unary `+` forces an integral promotion before overload resolution is performed.

Comment: You better report it before it's in the final 2015 version ;)

Comment: @Axalo It's been there for a while now. I'd be surprised if someone didn't report it before...